# How do disable VPN gateway when connected?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, vpn

I am connecting to my VPN from android device (4.0.3) using PPTP.
Everything works except I would like it not to use default gateway from VPN.

Same thing as you would do in windows when setting up VPN connection.

So how do I do that in android?